# CUDA Transfer Timing using events vs windows

Tags: cuda, memcpy

I'm transferring up 48kb data blocks (with pinned memory), and although cuda events see it go up at 5gb/sec, by the time we get back to windows we only see half that speed. Is this just unavoidable driver overhead, or are there ways to mitigate this? I've encapsulated the process in the test program below.

```
void transferUp(size_t size)
{

StopWatchWin timer;
timer.start();

float tUpCopyStart,tUpCopyStop;

cudaEvent_t sendUpStopEvent,sendUpStartEvent;
checkCudaErrors(cudaEventCreate( &sendUpStartEvent ));
checkCudaErrors(cudaEventCreate( &sendUpStopEvent ));

unsigned *cpu_sending = (unsigned *)malloc(size);
checkCudaErrors(cudaHostAlloc(&cpu_sending, size*sizeof(unsigned), cudaHostAllocPortable));

unsigned *gpu_receiving;
checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&gpu_receiving, size*sizeof(unsigned)));

tUpCopyStart = timer.getTime();
checkCudaErrors(cudaEventRecord(sendUpStartEvent));

checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpyAsync(gpu_receiving, cpu_sending, size*sizeof(unsigned), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

checkCudaErrors(cudaEventRecord(sendUpStopEvent));
checkCudaErrors(cudaEventSynchronize(sendUpStopEvent));
tUpCopyStop = timer.getTime();

double sendTimeWindows = tUpCopyStop - tUpCopyStart;

float sendTimeCuda;
checkCudaErrors(cudaEventElapsedTime( &sendTimeCuda,sendUpStartEvent,sendUpStopEvent));

float GbSec_cuda = (size*sizeof(unsigned)/1000)/(sendTimeCuda*1000);
float GbSec_win = (size*sizeof(unsigned)/1000)/(sendTimeWindows*1000);

printf("size=%06d bytes eventTime=%.03fms windowsTime=%0.3fms cudaSpeed=%.01f gb/s winSpeed=%.01f gb/s\n",
size*sizeof(unsigned),sendTimeCuda,sendTimeWindows,GbSec_cuda,GbSec_win);

checkCudaErrors(cudaEventDestroy( sendUpStartEvent ));
checkCudaErrors(cudaEventDestroy( sendUpStopEvent ));

checkCudaErrors(cudaFreeHost(cpu_sending));
checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(gpu_receiving));

}
```

Comment: Are you running in TCC?

Comment: Tiny C Compiler? No, visual studio 2010.

Comment: @sedona2222: TCC = Tesla Compute Cluster, the dedicated non display driver for CUDA on Windows platforms

Comment: Ah yes I remember. But no, not using it.

Comment: At full PCIe B/W a 48 kiB transfer will take ~6µs (assuming 8 GiB/s). The overhead to issue the memory copy and synchronize on WDDM is > 6 µs so yes you are encountering CUDA driver and WDDM overhead. If you traced your program in Nsight VSE or Visual Profiler this will be very easy to see on the timeline.

Answer (score 1):

The overhead of timing this small operation is overwhelming the measurement.

For small host->device copies (e.g., 64K or smaller), the CUDA driver will inline the data into the command buffer, so even the purportedly-synchronous memcpy calls are actually done asynchronously.  But, the `cudaEventSynchronize()` call in your code forces the CPU to wait instead of continuing execution.